# How convert country name to Iso2code on android?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have an AutoCompleteTextView for entering the country names. I have the list in and xml file like this:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="countries_array">
<item>Afghanistan</item>
<item>Albania</item>
<item>Algeria</item>
<item>American Samoa</item>
<item>Andorra</item>
and so on
```

But in another part of my app I need to have these names in ISO2code like Al for Albania and FR fro France. Do you have any idea? Does XML provide any other feature to put value for each item?

I was thinking to have another xml file just for Iso2code of country names then when an actual country name is chosen, it get the same number but from iso2code. But do not know how that would work.

So any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Locale you can get the country name from the ISO2 country code. So you can have a list of countries, list of country code, map of Country-ISO2 or reverse lookup map without the xml.

Look at the answer here:
[ISO2 country code from country name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155049/iso2-country-code-from-country-name)

Comment: Thanks for your post. I tried it but some how this map does not work on my android app as it has HashMap<>() which seems not acceptable its java version. Is there any other way ?

Comment: There was a mistake in the original code, it is not `Map<String, String> countries = new HashMap<>();` but `Map<String, String> countries = new HashMap<String,String>();`