# Android Locale Country name to Country code

Tags: android, localization

I have some country variable, "France" for example.
I want to get the country code, in this example, I want to get "FR" or "fr".

I tried :

```
 Locale locale = new Locale("", "FRANCE");
 Log.e("test", locale.getCountry());
```

But it returns :

```
 FRANCE
```

What I'm missing ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the built-in Locale class:

```
Locale l = new Locale("", "CH");
System.out.println(l.getDisplayCountry());
```

prints "Switzerland" for example. Note that I have not provided a language.

So what you can do for the reverse lookup is build a map from the available countries:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Map<String, String> countries = new HashMap<>();
    for (String iso : Locale.getISOCountries()) {
        Locale l = new Locale("", iso);
        countries.put(l.getDisplayCountry(), iso);
    }

    System.out.println(countries.get("Switzerland"));
    System.out.println(countries.get("Andorra"));
    System.out.println(countries.get("Japan"));
}
```

Answer found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155049/iso2-country-code-from-country-name). Hope it helps.