# Matching Locale from supported languages

Tags: android, ios, xml, localization

I am having trouble with supporting multiple languages. I have a list of strings in multiple languages on a sever and I am downloading them on runtime. For every string there is a list of supported languages formatted like `"en-US", "nl-NL"` etc.

I want my app to pick the best matching translation for the default Locale. If there is no best, it should pick `en-US`

An example for iOS is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2418/_index.html)

Do you know a solution or a library that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in Locale class:

```
Locale l = new Locale("", "CH");
System.out.println(l.getDisplayCountry());
```

prints "Switzerland" for example. Note that I have not provided a language.

So what you can do for the reverse lookup is build a map from the available countries:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
Map<String, String> countries = new HashMap<>();
for (String iso : Locale.getISOCountries()) {
Locale l = new Locale("", iso);
countries.put(l.getDisplayCountry(), iso);
  }


 System.out.println(countries.get("Switzerland"));
 System.out.println(countries.get("Andorra"));
 System.out.println(countries.get("Japan"));
 }
```

Here you can see more.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155049/iso2-country-code-from-country-name)

Comment: How does this give me the best matching Locale? If my Locale is nl-BE and there is no nl-BE it should return nl-NL, because thats the best matching. with the country code i cant match BE with NL