# Java API which return language code from language display name

Tags: localization, java-8

I have a service which gives the language display name as part of response. I want to retrieve the language code so that I can apply the internationalization for output file.

```
Expected input : English - United States
Output : en_US
```

Comment: You can loop over the [available locales](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales--) and look for a match.

Comment: please see answers for this question  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155049/iso2-country-code-from-country-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use something like that:

```
Optional<Locale> locale = Arrays.stream(Locale.getAvailableLocales())
        .filter(l ->
                l.getDisplayLanguage().equals("English") &&
                l.getDisplayCountry().equals("United States")
        ).findAny();

locale.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```